# How to insert date into SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've got this error:

> Cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String, java.util.Date)'

In the code below:
[image]

`lsd` and `nsd` are the column names with data type DATE.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String query="CREATE TABLE"+c_tablename+"(c_id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,name varchar(20),contact double ,address varchar(50)," +
            "bike_number varchar(16),bike_type varchar(10),lsd date,nsd date,lwd varchar(100),cost int,message varchar(100))";
    db.execSQL(query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    String query= "DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+c_tablename;
    String query2="DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+h_tablename;
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL(query2);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void  saveData(String name , int contact , String address , String bike_number , String bike_type , java.util.Date lsd  ,
                      java.util.Date nsd , String lwd , int cost , String message )
{
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name",name);
    contentValues.put("contact",contact);
    contentValues.put("address",address);
    contentValues.put("bike_number",bike_number);
    contentValues.put("bike_type",bike_type);
    contentValues.put("lsd",lsd);
    // The error is in the following line ("Cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String, java.util.Date)'"):
    contentValues.put("nsd",nsd);
    contentValues.put("lwd",lwd);
    contentValues.put("cost",cost);
    contentValues.put("message",message);
}
```

Comment: pls click on  ( enter image description here ) in above question to see the image with error

Comment: error is at the lsd and nsd ->
contentValues.put("lsd",lsd);
    contentValues.put("nsd",nsd);

 can not resolve the method'put(java.lang.String ,java.util.Date)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi can you try something like this,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("lsd", dateFormat.format(lsd));
```

Comment: yup the red  line error is now gone .. :) but my Question is will it take any date now??? without bothering ryt??

Answer (score 4):

**Akshay** shows the right solution to your problem.

The background information is that SQLite does not support a date type:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values

See SQLite documentation at https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_2_2